# Disable submit button after submit and page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

What i want is pretty simple, i have a button that submits a value to my database once clicked, what i need is to diable the button parmanently after value has been submited, i have searched and the codes i have seen all enable the button when the page refreshes.. please can someone help me out?

My form and button code as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="POST" name="Status2" id="Status2" onSubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
      <input name="Confirm2" type="checkbox" id="Confirm2" value="Confirmed" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
      <label for="Confirm2"></label>
      <input name="UpdateButton3" type="submit" class="art-button" id="UpdateButton3" value="Confirm"/>
      <input name="UserIDHiddenField4" type="hidden" id="UserIDHiddenField4" value="<?php echo $row_User['UserID']; ?>">
      <input name="Purge2" type="checkbox" id="Purge2" value="You Will Be Rematched Soon!" checked="CHECKED" style="display:none;">
      <label for="Purge2"></label>
      <input type="hidden" name="MM_update" value="Status2">
    </form>
```

Comment: You could set a session value (php) or a localstorage value (javascript) if that value exist disable the button.

Comment: Check value from database.. if set add disabled attribute to button

Comment: To transfer over values from 1 page to another, use a session. You could also store value in a database for that specific user that would state if that submit button is disabled or not.

Comment: @kodecount session or localstorage would only be for that session. He said it needs to be permanent

Comment: @georoot Missed that. Database would be best solution then.

Comment: Where's your php for the form?

Comment: use one filed for this table and default set 0 and after form submit then set 1 and all time check field value

Comment: I guess you would need an authentification system if you dont have one

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you submit it, this has nothing to do with javascript. Save this in your database as @georoot says. Then when you submit, save a value in the database. If that value is set, you can disable the button by just HTML: 
`<input type="submit" <?php if($valueFromDatabase==1){ ?> disabled <?php } ?> >`

Answer (score 0):

Best solution could be to set a cookie on client system and/or get user IP and save it into your database, but you should keep in mind, non of them are permanent ! The IP can be changed and the cookie can be removed ! But you can use both cookie and IP check.

Then for each page load, just check if cookie exist (compare the value with ur database value) and/or client IP is already exist in database.

Or if you know who is on the page (if it's a logged user) just add a field in your database and set value = 1 or = 0 and check the field each time it's loaded for same field and for same user.

**I wouldn't recommend to use IP check without cookies ! Because it can change frequency !**

Comment: Whats the thing with IP's here? Who says OP doesnt have an authentication system?